# Delete path of shape behind another shape in Inkscape

Tags: vector, inkscape

I would like to create the illusion of one shape being "on top" of another shape in Inkscape.

Is there a quick way to delete the path of one shape that is inside of another?  It is important that I not just hide the path, but actually remove it, and that there are not 2 identical paths on top of each other.

Below in the example I am trying to transform the overlapping circles on the left to show up like the circles on the right, where one appears on top of the other.

[image]

Comment: Using the background color as the fill color would probably be the simplest to work with. In this example you'd use white fill color. — I often do that and when I know I'm not going to make anymore changes, I finalize it by getting rid of the fill and the cut the extra lines away. Because as I think you know, if you delete that line now, you can't really move the circles around independently and explore things... — Though the finalization kinda depends on where and how it's going to be used. If it's a logo, sure, but if it's just a one time printed thing, I might just leave the fill color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy the lower circle <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, then Paste in Place <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

With the bottom circle still selected hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> as you also select the top circle.  Now you have two circles selected.

Click *Path > Cut Path* or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

Select and delete the part that has been cut.

[image]

Comment: Instead of [Ctrl]+[C] and [Ctrl]+[Alt]+[V], you can use [Ctrl]+[D] to duplicate in place.

Comment: To give a more generalizable instruction: you need to duplicate the upper object (in the z order or stacking order), because it will be consumed by the Path > Cut Path operation.

Comment: Is there a way to delete the wanted section without manually selecting it? (I ask as I have a complicated shape with many many of these sections that need to be removed)

Comment: @ElRudi Not really. You have to select something to enable deletion in Inkscape - it's the way to tell the application which objects to delete. You may be able to semi-automate the selection of multiple objects by using the options under *Edit > Select Same* - you can choose stroke/fill/stroke style/object type etc.

Comment: Thanks for getting back so fast on this old thread. I was hoping there'd be a way to reuse the (in this example) upper circle, e.g. by copying and pasting it in place. And then use 'remove paths below object' or something like that. But that doesn't seem to exist / 'path -> difference' doesn't work here, I'm thinking because it can only act on 2 objects

Comment: @ElRuydi - perhaps you should ask this as a new question. There are methods to use boolean operations on more than two objects, such as by using combined/compound paths.  However, you'd really need to show an example of what you are trying to achieve to get a specific answer.